# Why am I getting the following error? "No unique bean of type is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3"

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, spring-security

We use Eclipse Kepler IDE to develop our GWT app and have been using an Ant script to deploy to a Tomcat container for a long time.  We recently decided to switch to using a Hudson CI server in order to streamline the GWT compile and deploy process.  The problem we are encountering is that when we allow Eclipse to do it's own continuous building, then perform the GWT compile/deploy, our app works as expected.  However, when we use an external javac process to compile, whether from a standalone JDK or using Eclipse's compiler (`org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter`), we receive the following error message:

```
Error creating bean with name 'loginServiceImpl' defined in file [/opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT##10616/WEB-INF/classes/com/company/ribeye/server/service/LoginServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager]: : No unique bean of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: [org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0, org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0, org.springframework.security.authenticationManager]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 3: [org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0, org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0, org.springframework.security.authenticationManager]
```

We are not using any sort of dependency manager, yet Eclipse seems to handle the java compilation without issue and we don't encounter this error.  I want to stress this error only occurs when we compile using an Ant task and javac.  Again, even when using Eclipse's own bundled compiler we have the problem.  I also want to add that I am not a Java developer but I am the DevOps manager for our development team, so the CI server and deploy strategy fall within my domain.  I have a little Java knowledge and am still learning, so if this is something incredibly simple, I apologise in advance.

Here's my relevant code (not all imports listed, for brevity's sake):

```
package com.company.ribeye.server.service;


import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginServiceImpl extends GWTController implements LoginService {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final UserDao userDao;
    private final UserPreferenceDao userPreferenceDao;

    @Autowired
    public LoginServiceImpl(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, UserDao userDao, UserPreferenceDao userPreferenceDao) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.userDao = userDao;
        this.userPreferenceDao = userPreferenceDao;
    }

    @Override
    public ApplicationData getApplicationData() {
        ApplicationData ap = new ApplicationData();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
        ap.setCurrentYear(Integer.parseInt(df.format(new Date())));
        ap.setLoggedIn(false);

        if (!ServerContext.isProductionServer() && ServerContext.isDevServer()) {
            Pair<String, String> login = ServerContext.getDevAutoLogin();
            ap.setDevModeAutoUsername(login.getA());
            ap.setDevModeAutoPassword(login.getB());
        }

        if (ServerContext.getSession().getAttribute(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY) == null) {
            return ap;
        }

        User user = ServerContext.getCurrentUser();

        if (user == null) {
            return ap;
        }
        ApplicationContext ctx = ServerContext.getApplicationContext();

        if (user.isPortalUser()) {
            CustomerDao customerDao = (CustomerDao) ctx.getBean("customerDaoImpl");
            user.setCustomer(customerDao.getById(user.getCustomerId()));
        } else if (user.isVendorUser()) {
            VendorDao vendorDao = (VendorDao) ctx.getBean("vendorDaoImpl");
            user.setVendor(vendorDao.getById(user.getVendorId()));
        }

        ap.setLoggedIn(true);
        ap.setDashDatabaseConnection(DashDataSourceContextHolder.getDatabaseType());
        ap.setBuildNumber(ServerContext.getBuildNumber());
        ap.setBuildDate(ServerContext.getBuildDate());
        ap.setNextReleaseDate(ServerContext.getNextReleaseDate());
        ap.setCurrentUser(user);
        ap.setUserLinks(userPreferenceDao.getUserLinks(user.getId()));
        ap.setMyContacts(userPreferenceDao.getMyContacts());
        if (!user.isSwitched()) {
            UserDaoImpl.updateUserActivity(user.getId());
        }
        ap.setUserActivity(UserDaoImpl.getAllUserActivity());

        SystemDao systemDao = (SystemDao) ctx.getBean("systemDaoImpl");
        ap.setEntityLinkers(systemDao.getEntityLinkers());
        PollUpdateData pud = new PollUpdateData(user.getId());
        ap.setNotificationSummary(systemDao.getPollData(pud).getNotificationSummary());
        ap.setNotificationEntityTypeColors(systemDao.getNotificationEntityTypeColors());
        ap.setUserPreferences(userPreferenceDao.getPreferencesByGroupName(user.getId(), null));

        ArgMap<FlagArg> flagArgs = new ArgMap<FlagArg>();
        flagArgs.put(FlagArg.USER_ID, user.getId());
        ap.setFlagDefinitions(Common.asArrayList(userPreferenceDao.getFlagDefinitions(flagArgs)));

        DocumentDao documentDao = (DocumentDao) ctx.getBean("documentDaoImpl");
        ap.setLogoImage(documentDao.getLogoImage());

        return ap;
    }
```

Here is the relevant portion of our applicationContext-security.xml:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
            <salt-source ref="saltSource" />
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>


<beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
<beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
    <beans:property name="userSearch">
        <beans:bean id="userSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
            <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="" />
            <beans:constructor-arg index="1" value="REDACTED" />
            <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:constructor-arg>

<beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
         <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
         <beans:constructor-arg value="REDACTED" />
         <beans:property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="cn" />
         <beans:property name="searchSubtree" value="false" />
         <beans:property name="convertToUpperCase" value="true" />
         <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_" />
         <beans:property name="groupSearchFilter" value="member={0}" />
         <beans:property name="defaultRole" value="ROLE_DASH" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:constructor-arg>
```

And dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.ribeye.server.service" />
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.ribeye.server.dao" />
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.ribeye.server.util" />
  <context:annotation-config />
  <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
</beans>
```

customUserDetailsService, as requested:

```
package com.company.ribeye.server.spring;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate sjt;

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        RowMapper<User> mapper = new RowMapper<User>() {
            @Override
            public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

                return new User(rs.getString("Login"), rs.getString("PasswordDigest"), rs.getBoolean("IsEnabled"), rs.getBoolean("IsEnabled"), true, true,
                        getAuthorities(rs));
            }
        };

        User user;

        String sql = "select top 1 u.ID, u.Login, u.PasswordDigest, u.CustomerID, u.VendorID, u.IsPortalSuperUser, ";
        sql += "dbo.IsActive(u.StartDate, u.EndDate, getdate()) as IsEnabled from Users u ";
        sql += "where u.Login = ? and PasswordDigest is not null";

        try {
            user = sjt.queryForObject(sql, mapper, username);
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }

        return user;
    }

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        sjt = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        final List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        if (rs.getInt("VendorID") > 0) {
            authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_COMPANY_DASH_USERS"));
            return authList;
        }
        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_PORTAL_USER"));
        if (rs.getBoolean("IsPortalSuperUser")) {
            authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_PORTAL_SUPERUSER"));
            authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_PORTAL_BILLING"));
            authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_PORTAL_OPERATIONS"));
            return authList;
        }

        // if not a superuser, fetch account-level roles from database
        RowMapper<List<GrantedAuthority>> mapper = new RowMapper<List<GrantedAuthority>>() {
            @Override
            public List<GrantedAuthority> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                if (rs.getInt("Billing") > 0) {
                    authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_PORTAL_BILLING"));
                }
                if (rs.getInt("Operations") > 0) {
                    authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_PORTAL_OPERATIONS"));
                }

                return authList;
            }
        };
        String sql = "select sum(cast(Billing as int)) as Billing, sum(cast(Operations as int)) as Operations ";
        sql += "from PortalUserRoles ";
        sql += "where UserID = ?";
        sjt.queryForObject(sql, mapper, rs.getInt("ID"));

        return authList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you copy your CustomUserDetailsService?

Comment: CustomUserDetailsService added.  :)

Comment: Your LoginServiceImpl seems to be a controller and it doesnt have @Controller annotation

Comment: I must have left off the @Controller annotation when I was pasting the code, I assure you it wasn't intentional and we have been using it.  Updated my question to reflect the correct annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching, I was able to find the solution, given to me by someone on #spring (freenode).  I still don't know why this wasn't a problem inside Eclipse, but at least it's working now.

Although I couldn't find in our app where the other two beans were being created, adding `@Qualifier("authenticationManager")` annotation to LoginServiceImpl solved the problem:

```
@Autowired
    public LoginServiceImpl(@Qualifier("authenticationManager") AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, UserDao userDao,
            UserPreferenceDao userPreferenceDao) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.userDao = userDao;
        this.userPreferenceDao = userPreferenceDao;
    }
```